# column name plus one for loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have name1, name2, name3 in mysql how do a do a 'for loop' to retreive the names of each person in mysql which i need to do for my form validation.

```
    <?php
$row2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($row2) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

In the form, I'm using the following, but it is not retrieving the names:

```
        for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) 
// form code
    <?php echo $row3['name'+[$i]]?>');
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a client-side `for` loop? You need to do it all in your PHP.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes it is all working i just need the code for a for loop

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns both numeric and associative keys by default, so your incremental for loop won't give you what you want. Instead, use the `MYSQL_ASSOC` option or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
// OR
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

The `for` loop has to be done in PHP. It is difficult to tell if your loop is client side or server side.

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
  // not 'name' + $i -- PHP uses '.' for concatenation
  // but it is easier to interpolate it in double quotes.
  echo $row3["name$i"];
}
?>
```

#### Update

Since you were trying to mix PHP into a JS loop (which won't work), I recommend instead creating a JavaScript array using PHP, which can then be used in the JS loop later.

```
<?php
  // Open a JS array called namesArray
  echo "var namesArray = [";
  $names = array();
  for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
    // get all the column values into an array
    $names[] = '"' . $row3["name$i"] . '"';
  }
  // Make it into a string
  $names = implode(',', $names);
  // Close the JS array
  echo $names . "];"
?>
```

That should output something like:

```
var namesArray = ["val1","val2","val3","val4","val5"];
```

In your JavaScript loop (which you don't have to change), access the values like:

```
 // Updated to use i-1 instead of i
 alert('Please make your colour & shade selection for ' + namesArray[i-1]);
```

Comment: thanks and is this correct? for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) 
<?php echo $row3['name'+[$i]]?>');

Comment: thanks for your help. I have uplaoded my code to http://pastebin.com/W0bt7t4h ... Can you check for flaws as it is still failing to work

Comment: can you confirm http://pastebin.com/qCpdSZBG . also at the header it has "var namesArray =" with all of the names so its working ok.

Comment: yea its coming out of a jquery.js script tag :s. there is no error when 'please select' is selected

Comment: @jing I cannot see your pastebin docs anymore, but I think the issue may be that you were using `for($i=0....)` in your JavaScript for loop but inside we used `namesArray[i]` (no $).  Change one or the other of them.  The other thing is that your loop started with 1 but mine started with 0. See the change to the last line above to rectify that...

Comment: I have also tried http://pastebin.com/QceKv661 which is not working either (no error) upon submit when please select is selected

Comment: Michael I have made an unlimited version. This is the full php and jquery script .... http://pastebin.com/N69WPJ84

Comment: i would be greatful if you could look at it and tell me where i am going wrong as ive been trying all day

Comment: i did change them all to -1 earlier. My form looks like this: jsfiddle.net/cZSHK . At present if batman has filled in his selection 'yes', 'red' and 'light' and i click submit it comes up an error "please select colour and shade for Batman". The batman should be superman as batmans has made selection. 

I have tried it with up to 5 people and it just returns the first name all the time in the error message

Comment: ok changed the id's to yes1 no1 and yes2 no2 which does not make a difference. How do I debug $("#colour" + $i)[0].selectedIndex. if it is returning an error does this not mean it is working as it just the names that i am having issues with?

Comment: If it comes up with an error on the first loop iteration each time, then the logic which tests for selections is broken.  `console.log($("#colour" + $i)[0].selectedIndex);`

Comment: when i replace with else if console.log($("#colour" + $i)[0].selectedIndex == 0). no errors are displayed at all

Comment: @jing `console.log()` is a debugging statement. Place it inside the if block and open your browser's error console (Firebug extension recommended for Firefox, Chrome/Safari have  developer tools , F12 brings up console in IE.)

Comment: I put in a static array of names ( to simulate the PHP generated one) and this whole thing appears to work with `$i-1` as the array indices: http://jsfiddle.net/cZSHK/1/

Comment: ran debug and comes up error line 154...... if ($("#colour" + $i)[0].selectedIndex == 0 && $("#shade" + $i)[0].selectedIndex == 0)

Comment: your example does not work with me. select spiderman 'yes' you see the way it says please select colour and shade for batman? it should be spiderman

Comment: @jing see http://jsfiddle.net/cZSHK/8/ , which is doing exactly as it is coded for. On any click of any radio button, the whole loop runs and displays an error for the first name having a missing selection.So if batman still hasn't made a choice and you click spiderman's button, batman will get a warning. If that isnt' the way it is supposed to work, the whole algorithm will need to be rewritten.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cZSHK/10/ The trick is to check if yes/no is enabled _inside_ the loop and then add that condition (`nameEnabled`) to each of the three checks in the `if/else` chain.

Comment: great and how do I remove the prompt when I select yes as I only want the error displayed on submit click

Comment: @jing Remove the `click()` binding line `$("input[name^='attendance']").click(function(){...});`

Comment: brilliant all working now, just one small thing. When I click attending 'yes' for each person then click submit without selecting drop downs it says "please select food and drink for batman" 5 times. How do I just say batman once.

Comment: e.g http://jsfiddle.net/cZSHK/14/ mark batman and superman 'yes' then click submit. You see the way 2 error messages appear?

Comment: @jing You called the `validate()` function twice via `$.each` on the submit click. Since the loop happens _inside_ the function, it should only be called once, and it doesn't matter what `id` is passed in. http://jsfiddle.net/cZSHK/15/ I commented out the `$.each` and just called `validate(1)`.

Comment: :D one last thing i promise.. If neither attendance colour and food is selected how do display please select attendance, colour and food for USER

Comment: and also grey out(disable) the colour and shade drop downs until attendance is selected

Comment: @jing You really need to start asking new questions for these, which are not related at all to your original issue.  To grey them out before selecting them, just set them all to `disabled='disabled'` in the original HTML. They'll be enabled when set to Yes.  And rather than forcing the user to select one, why not just default them all to No in the HTML?

Comment: when I click submit when no attendance is selected on radio button and my error pops up my jquery hint disappears however when attendance is selected with drop down at 'please select' selected an error occurs but then jquery remains like it should. how do i keep the jquery hint when no attendance is selected and submit is clicked?

Comment: @jing I don't even know what jQuery hint you're talking about, as I don't have that code. We cannot continue this on this question any longer - a comment thread this long is likely to attract attention of the site moderators, who will probably close and delete it.  Isolate out only the part of your code that is problematic right now, and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop needs to be inside the php tag.